# Calling Javascript function in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, clientscript

How am I able to show an alert to the user on a Web Application in C#? I'm trying to do so by calling on a JS function within the C# I'm writing, but am unsure of how to do so since Page.ClientScript isn't being recognized. Do I need a different namespace included?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Transactions;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Diagnostics;

.
.
.

while (physAuthToUpdate.start_date < physAuthToUpdate.end_date)
{
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "print", "<script>showAlertWindow('Error: End date cannot come before begin date.');</script>");
}
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager?view=netframework-4.8

And it may also be possible to simple use following if you want to show the alert inline:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('hello');</script>");
```

Comment: What namespace is necessary for Response?

Comment: System.Web Here is example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.write?view=netframework-4.8
Dont forget to upvote it it is helpful :)